# Detecting sequences in filenames/strings

Tags: ruby, regex, filenames

I have a list of filenames e.g.

- concept01.xyz
- concept02.xyz
- foo.xyz
- bar_concept.xyz
- bar2_concept.xyz
- bar3_concept.xyz
- hello.xyz
- hello_v2.xyz

What is the most efficient way to scan through the list and know that (concept1,2) is a sequence, (bar,2,3) is another, and (hello,2) is another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your list of filenames is an array, you could do something like this:

```
filenames.group_by {|f| f.match(/^[A-Za-z]+/)[0] }
```

Which will group the filenames by everything up to the first non-alphabetical character.

(Note: `.group_by` require Ruby 1.9+)